# Format vector of numbers prettily to the same number of decimal places

Tags: r

I am constructing pretty axis labes using `pretty()` function and I want to format them to the same number of decimal places. I tried this:

```
at <- pretty(c(0.001, 0.05), n = 7)
# [1] 0.000 0.005 0.010 0.015 0.020 0.025 0.030 0.035 0.040 0.045 0.050

prettyNum(at)
# [1] "0"     "0.005" "0.01"  "0.015" "0.02"  "0.025" "0.03"  "0.035" "0.04"  "0.045" "0.05"
```

You can see that `prettyNum()` is formatting the numbers prettily (e.g. the zero doesn't have decimal places), but it doesn't unify the number of decimal places in the other numbers (to have like "0.030" etc.). How can I do this? I tried `prettyNum(at, preserve.width = "common")` but the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sprintf`, which uses the same formatting as C's `printf`:

```r
sprintf("%.03f", 0.05)
```

Comment: I know `sprintf` ... this is not a solution, you just hardcoded `3` decimal places for this particular vector! ;-)

Comment: if you want the decimal places as a function, you can do a double `sprintf` or `paste0` to have it as a parameter.